# Is there an R/terminal query to get an overview of the functions and subfunctions within a model?

Tags: r

Currently I am working on quite a big model in R, whereof I would like to have an overview of which functions call which functions. I only need the functions that I have developed myself.

```
#call primary function
PF = primary_function(x = x,
                      y = y)
#within primary function
PF <- function(x,y){

  "code"
#call secundary function within primary function
  SF <- function(z = z)
  "code"

and so on
```

I would like to get an overview of the layers within the model and the functions within them. Is there an 'easy' way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there is no simple way. This is a very complex problem due to the dynamic nature of R. The same occurence of a variable could refer to a function or to data or to something else, depending on what was executed before. So you would need to simulate all possible paths your program could take.
However, in theory it could well be possible to get a list of called (sub-)functions for a concrete call of the primary function. I am however not aware of any way to do this easily.

Comment: Perhaps parsing the code to get an abstract syntax tree (AST) could be helpful (eg. via `rlang::parse_exprs` and the package `codetools`)

Comment: Since you are interested only in the functions that you have developed yourself you could also add logging output at the beginning and each exit point of your functions (eg. with the package `futile.logger` and `flog.info("Entered function xy...")` + `flog.info("Exiting function xy")` to get the execution flow printed in the console when you execute your code. Logging is best practice btw... (eg. by also logging the function argument values for debugging or compliance)

Comment: (While I have nothing against `futile.logger`, the same effect can be had using `message(.)`, optionally conditioned on something like `options(myverbose=TRUE)` on the console, then your functions could log with `if (getOption("myverbose",FALSE)) message(...)`. *Not a replacement* for formal logging, just a hack to get the minimum.)

Comment: (On that note, you can simplify a little by defining your functions with `myfunc <- function(..., verbose = getOption("myverbose", 0L)) { ... }`, then sprinkled throughout your code you can use `if (verbose > 1) message("...")` for simple messages and `if (verbose > 2) message("...")` for more detailed logging. Then, when you want to see this logging, on the console run `options(myverbose=2)` and you'll get lots of messages, or `options(myverbose=1)` for simple stuff.)